# bootstrap tour cookie end

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, cookies

I'm trying to add a cookie to the tour so when it ends it doesnt show again when you revisit the page this is my code:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({stack:true});
var t = new Tour({
    backdrop: true,
    onShown: function(tour) {
        var stepElement = getTourElement(tour);
        $(stepElement).after($('.tour-step-background'));
        $(stepElement).after($('.tour-backdrop'));
    }
});

t.addStep({
    element: "#red",
    title: "red",
    content: "Content"
});
t.addStep({
    element: "#red-stripe",
    title: "stripes",
    content: "Content"
});
t.addStep({
    element: "#p",
    title: "Title",
    content: "Content"
});

$.cookie('endcookie', 'end', { expires: 7 });
t.restart();

function getTourElement(tour){
    return tour._steps[tour._current].element
}
```

this didnt work

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't be necessary to use a cookie for this. Bootstrap Tour uses your browser's localStorage to make sure that the user doesn't see the tour more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Before you call again the `tour.start()`, use one `tour.restart()`. This worked for me to solve the problem of reopening.